# Similar procedure to assoc that returns list of matching items

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm not aware of any built in Scheme procedures that will take a key and return a list. Example:

```
(define data-a '((a 1) (b 2) (c 3) (a 4)))
(assoc 'a data-a)
```

That would return something like:

```
((a 1)(a 4))
```

Has anyone encountered anything similar? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to write one:

```
(define (assoc-all key alist)
  (filter (lambda (a) (equal? key (car a))) alist))
```

Comment: Ah, perfect. I was trying this but instead of filter I was trying to use `assoc`. Thank you.